# how to sub two numbers from user in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote this statement in Assembly language but there is error in the `sub`, how can I subtract two numbers from *user*?

```
statment2_:
  mov num2,bh
  mov num1,bl
  ADD num1 ,30h
  SUB num2 ,num1
```

- num1 and num2 are from the user,
- bh is number 1, and
- bl is number 2

Comment: Put one of 'em in a register. Two memory operands won't work (generally). `sub num2, bh` may work for ya...

Comment: @FrankKotler funnily enough they are already in registers :) Hm, or maybe they aren't but then he got the `mov` operands in reversed order.

Comment: @Jester Yeah. I got it backwards - he wants to subtract `bl`. But the "error in the sub" is from two memory operands, I think. What we don't know (does BSMN?) is whether the register/variable is the character '1' or the number 1. Maybe he'll tell us... I think he's gone...

Comment: @FrankKotler I read the 2 number from user , then I moved them one to bh and the other to bl , then I moved them again to the num1 and num2 , so I cannt SUB them ? If i SUB num2,bl < is that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of latest information, we've got two characters from the user - '2' and '1', in variables "num1" and "num2". What you probably want to do is...

```
mov bl, num1
mov bh, num2
sub bl, '0'
sub bh, '0'
; now we've got two numbers we can do arithmetic on
sub bh, bl
; now we need a character we can print
add bh, '0'
; and print it
mov al, bh
int 29h
; or other method of your choice
```

This will only work for single-digit numbers. For multiple digits (or negative numbers) something more complicated is required - check out the examples listed on the right...

What you can't do is subtract two memory operands (variables). At least one of 'em has to be a register or immediate value.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have numbers in registers, you don't need to store them to memory.  IDK why you're messing around with `num1` and `num2`.

---

When you say "from user", it seems you mean an ASCII digit.  So you actually have `bl = n1 + '0'` (where `'0'` is the ASCII code for the ASCII character `0`).

Subtraction cancels out this offset, because `(n2+'0') - (n1+'0') = n2 - n1` :

```
sub  bl, bh    ; bl = integer difference, -9 .. +9
```

If you want to turn that integer back into an ASCII code for a digit, then (assuming the subtraction result was positive and in the 0..9 range, so it can be represented by a single ASCII digit):

```
add  bl, '0'   ; convert a 0..9 integer to the ASCII code for that digit.
```